# Hacer un cat y un grep dentro de /etc/passwd para compararlos con otro archivo de texto en python

Tags: python

Estoy creando un script que a partir de una lista de nombres de usuario contenida en el archivo patata.txt , uno por línea, determine si el usuario existe o no. El script mostrará un listado con los usuarios que figuran en el archivo patata.txt pero que no existan en el sistema. 
Actualmente estoy probando con el siguiente código pero evidentemente, no me funciona, cualquier ayuda se agradece.

```
import re
f = open("/home/patata.txt")
for linea in f:
    usuario = linea[:-1]
    with open("/etc/passwd", "r") as file:
        for line in file:
            if re.search(usuario, line):
               if line != usuario:
                    print(usuario)
f.close()
```

Comment: Nada es evidente. Por qué dices que no funciona? Qué pones en patata.txt?

Comment: en patata.txt pongo 4 usuarios 2 que están en /etc/passwd y 2 que no. Digo que no me funciona porque si no, no estaría preguntando xD . Te invito a probar el código.

Comment: Te invito a que nos pongas datos de prueba que tú estés usando ;) por lo que sabemos hasta ahora, puede ser ese el problema (por formato o contenido)! Decir "no funciona" siempre es mala idea describiendo un problema de programación

Comment: El fichero patata: https://prnt.sc/22n727l 
 Y el resultado del programa el cual es erróneo. https://prnt.sc/22n7dsa

Comment: Acabo de correr tu código con una ruta correcta y un archivo patata con 4 usuarios, dos existentes, y la salida son los dos usuarios existentes. No se replica, corre peligro que se cierre la pregunta... revisa la ruta al archivo patata. Te invito a que leas el código. ;)  PD. No sé si es el adblocker o qué, pero no puedo ver ni el fichero ni la salida. Ponlos como texto en la pregunta usando la opción [edit], por favor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La causa inmediata del problema está aquí:

```
if re.search(usuario, line):
    if line != usuario:
        print(usuario)
```

La función `re.search` retorna `True` cuando el usuario está en la línea leida. En tal caso, la siguiente condición

```
if line != usuario:
```

siempre se cumple, pues `usuario` es un nombre como `Jose` y `line` contiene toda una línea del archivo `/etc/passwd`

```
nobody:x:65534:65534:nobody:/nonexistent:/usr/sbin/nologin
```

Nunca será iguales.

En definitiva, tu código imprime los nombres que **si** están en `/etc/passwd`.

#### Solución

Cambio de enfoque: primero leemos todo `/etc/passwd` extrayendo los nombres de usuarios, que es el primer campo en cada línea.

```
usuarios_sistema = []
with open("/etc/passwd", "r") as passwords:
    for linea in passwords:
        user = linea.split(":")[0]
        usuarios_sistema.append(user)
```

El resultado es una lista con los usuarios del sistema.

A continuación recorremos el archivo de usuarios candidatos y sólo nos queda ver si el código está o no en la lista del sistema:

```
with open("/home/patata.txt") as candidatos:
    for linea in candidatos:
        usuario = linea[:-1]
        if usuario not in usuarios_sistema:
            print(usuario)
```

#### Demo

*/home/patata.txt*

```
jose
andres
candid
raul
```

*código*

```
import re

usuarios_sistema = []
with open("/etc/passwd", "r") as passwords:
    for linea in passwords:
        user = linea.split(":")[0]
        usuarios_sistema.append(user)

with open("/home/patata.txt") as candidatos:
    for linea in candidatos:
        usuario = linea[:-1]
        if usuario not in usuarios_sistema:
            print(usuario)
```

produce:

```
jose
andres
raul

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: De cine, gracias, la verdad es mas fácil así